# Magento2 : How to translate attribute group Label?

Tags: magento2, attributes, translate

In magento we can translate attribute label by store.
But how can we translate Attribute Group Label
[image]
By default label will be same for all store as there is no option for set label by Store. 
[image]

Comment: Did you manage to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can not translate attribute group on store / website level, however you can double click "Group Name" and rename it only.

Comment: Yes I know that,but if someone knows any method for making this possible

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using language pack.
Create Language pack at below path.

> app/i18n/[custom]/en_US

Note: I have taken "**en_US**" for sample you can create folder whatever language you want to use.